# mysql hotel room availability

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an availability table ind Mysql as follows:

```
id
room_id int(11)
avail_date date
```

For each room, there is a row for every date it is available.
It is possible that there are gaps,  for example room 1  might have entries for 1,2,3,5,6,13,14,15 of august, every other day it is not available.

I need a query to find a list of room_ids  where there is availabilty for every day within a date range.

In other words, get a list of room_ids where there is an entry for each room for each date between startdate and enddate.

Comment: typically you should post what you have tried.  This hotel question is a common one - like homework common, and this is not a do my homework site.

Comment: Even if it's homework, you'll get help if the question is properly asked: just be honest about it! :)

Comment: I´m sorry if I offended anyone with my question,  I just didn´t have a clue where to start trying to find the rooms with entries for consecutive days between two dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
select room_id
from availability a
where avail_date between $start and $end
group by room_id
having count(*) = datediff($end, $start) + 1;
```

The `having` clause is counting the number of rows during that period to see if it matches the number of days you need.  This is "inclusive" logic, so if `$start = $end`, then it assumes you need the room on that date.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Working perfectly